# Vue js switch css class

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component

I am using vuejs and I would like to switch my class depending on the data value.
If its a negative number, i would like to use the .neg class and when its a positive number, i would like to use the .pos class.

Everything is working, except for adding the class.

The data looks like this: 5, -7, 8, -2, 4, -9 ect

```
myArray: function () {
  var test =  [5, -7, 8, -2, 4, -9];
  return test;
},
```

---

```
<div v-for="data in myArray">
  <div v-bind:class="{'neg': data < 0, 'pos': data > 0}"></div>
  <div id="my">{{ data }}</div>
</div>
```

---

```
.pos {background-color: green;}
.neg {background-color: red;}
```

Any help would be appropriated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data in myArray()`? Also, I wouldn't keep re-using the "my" `id` in the loop. You'll end up with duplicates

Comment: Seems to work ok here ~ http://jsfiddle.net/o49x5de0/2/. Could it possibly be that your `neg` / `pos` classed elements have no content?

Comment: Voting to close as a *typo*

Comment: Thanks Phil, would give you an up vote if i could. My issue was myArray(). When i changed it, it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, myArray is returning a value (an array). Replace `myArray` with `myArray()`

```
<div v-for="data in myArray">
  <div :class="{'neg': data < 0, 'pos': data > 0}"></div>
  <div id="my">{{ data }}</div>
</div
```